# multilevel bootstrap menu only showing first level

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a multelevel menu with bootstrap 3 but can't get it to work and have insufficient knowledge of bootstrap to figure out why

The mark up is

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="" href="">Y<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a href="#" tabindex="-1">foo</a>         
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="">bar</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and css and js are included as below

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My expectation is that when I open the first menu ("Y") I can see a new menu item "foo" that can be opened to reveal the last item "bar"

The code is based on an example I found [here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3)

Comment: you should copy the css  from the example and it will work ...http://www.bootply.com/rzYsRfVGmk

Comment: Did you include the css styles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `CSS` from that snippet does all the trick regarding the multi level dropdowns. Please see the working snippet below:

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #ccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <a role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="" href="">Y<span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
      <a href="#" tabindex="-1">foo</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="">bar</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: your answer helped me fix the problem. It turned out my problem was two fold. You fixed one of them and the other was a bug in websharper.ui.next templating that I could work around. I've mark as the answer because any one facing the problem I describe should be able to fix as you describe and you included a snippet

Answer (score 1):

Following [the example](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3), you should try copying also the css styles:

```
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
    left: -100%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}
```

It should work if you add them. Let us know if you manage to make it work! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   
<div class="container">                                      
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Y
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">Foo <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Bar</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```